# get a value from function in php

Tags: php

i am trying  to do the paging in the php file.
i have written php function in function.php file and include that file in other php file.
the problem is how can i get the value of $count,$res in other php file.
in the other.php i am not getting value of $count,$res.

```
//function.php
function Paging($tbl_name,$targetpage,$where,$limit,$page,$qstr)
        {

            //$tbl_name="shopitup_productmaster";       //your table name
            // How many adjacent pages should be shown on each side?
            $adjacents = 3;

            /* 
               First get total number of rows in data table. 
               If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
            */
            $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name where ".$where;
            $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
            $total_pages = $total_pages[num];

            /* Setup vars for query. */
            //$targetpage = "paging.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
            //$limit = 2;                               //how many items to show per page
            //$page = $_GET['page'];
            if($page) 
                $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
            else
                $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

            /* Get data. */
            echo $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where ".$where." LIMIT $start, $limit";
            $res = mysql_query($sql);
            $count=mysql_num_rows($res);

            /* Setup page vars for display. */
            if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
            $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
            $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
            $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
            $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1         

            $pagination = "";
            if($lastpage > 1)
            {   
                $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
                //previous button
                if ($page > 1) 
                    $pagination.= '<a href="'.$targetpage.'?page='.$prev.$qstr.'">« previous</a>';
                else
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">previous</span>";   

                //pages 
                if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
                {   
                    for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                    {
                        if ($counter == $page)
                            $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                        else
                            $pagination.= '<a href="'.$targetpage.'?page='.$counter.$qstr.'">'.$counter.'</a>';                 
                    }
                }
                elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
                {
                    //close to beginning; only hide later pages
                    if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
                    {
                        for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                        {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter.$qstr\">$counter</a>";                   
                        }
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1.$qstr\">$lpm1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage.$qstr\">$lastpage</a>";     
                    }
                    //in middle; hide some front and some back
                    elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
                    {
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                        {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter.$qstr\">$counter</a>";                   
                        }
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1.$qstr\">$lpm1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage.$qstr\">$lastpage</a>";     
                    }
                    //close to end; only hide early pages
                    else
                    {
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1.$qstr\">1</a>";
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2.$qstr\">2</a>";
                        $pagination.= "...";
                        for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                        {
                            if ($counter == $page)
                                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                            else
                                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter.$qstr\">$counter</a>";                   
                        }
                    }
                }

                //next button
                if ($page < $counter - 1) 
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next.$qstr\">next</a>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next »</span>";
                $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
            }
        //return $pagination;   
           echo $pagination;


        }
?>
```

other.php

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    include("conn.php");
    include("function.php");
    $tbl="gallary"; 
    $tb="album";

 $aid=$_GET['aid'];
 $aname=$_GET['name'];  
?>


$where="aid='$aid'";
                     $limit="6";
                     $qstr="&aid=$aid";
                     $counter=1;
                     $tbl_name = "gallary";
                     $targetpage = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

                     if(strlen(trim($_GET['page'])) > 0)
                        {   $page =($_GET['page']); }

                        if($page) { $start = ($page - 1) * $limit; }            //first item to display on this page
                        else {  $start = 0; }

                    ?>


                    <?php $pagination=Paging($tbl_name,$targetpage,$where,$limit,$page,$qstr);?>
                     <?php echo "count=$count;"  ?>


<?php


    if($count==0)
    {?>
     <table align="center" style="padding-top:30px;">
     <tr><b>NO Image Available in this Album....!!!!</tr></table>
     <?
    }
    else
    {

                        $i=0;
                        for($j=1;$j<=$count;$j+=3)
                        {
                          ?>
                          <table align="center" style="padding-top:30px;">
                          <tr></tr>
                             <tr><td>
                          <?php

                            $row= mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
                            $img=stripslashes($row['image']);
                            $img_id=$row['eid'];
```

Comment: use return in Paging function with count and res to get values of these

Comment: Let me tell you that your coding is not very secure and performance friendly.

Comment: @AyeshK:HOW???pls tell me about this

Answer (score 1):

this is all about scope. Anything outside of the `Paging()` function cannot access that `$count` var because it is only available within the scope of `Paging()`

I would recommend bringing the database stuff back into other.php and just passing the Paging() function the stuff that's needed for echoing the navigation (total number of pages, target page, current page etc).

You could also try to create a global var, just before including functions.php, and then set the value inside your included script, like so:

```
...
session_start();
$count = 0;
include("conn.php");
include("function.php");
```

and in your functions.php:

```
...
$GLOBALS["count"] = mysql_num_rows($res);
```

Comment: are there any results in mysql_num_rows($res)?

Comment: try placing the database stuff inside other.php and let the Paging() function only handle echoing the links. This way, you have direct access to the results

Comment: yes working if i write function.php code inside other.php but i want to use paging for more than one page so that i am trying to write function.

Comment: as a third option, you can let Paging() return the number of results

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17689/discussion-between-swapnil-and-reinder)

Answer (score 0):

You could use 3 options there 
a.) use global variables (I wouldn't recommend this, but I want to mention it for sake of completeness).
b.) You return a class in the paging function
c.) You return an array in the paging function

I think b is a bit overdoing it in your case so I'll explain b.)

**function Paging($tbl_name,$targetpage,$where,$limit,$page,$qstr):**

At the end of your function your insert the following code:

```
$returnarray['pagination']=$pagination;
$returnarray['count']=$count;
$returnarray['res']=$res;
```

And then in your "other file" you use this lines:

```
$array=Paging($tbl_name,$targetpage,$where,$limit,$page,$qstr);
$pagination=$array['pagination'];
$count=$array['count'];
$res=$array['res'];
```

Always keep in mind that all variables have a scope in which they are set and valid. Thus if you use a variable within a method it is only valid within this one method, and NOT outside of it and also NOT in any methods called within the method itself.

Additionally you should think if you want to really return $res as a whole and not define an array instead where you already do the transformations you want to do later (thus that you do not return the resultset but the data already), but that is more a matter of taste there.

Global variables (a.) I would not recommend as it brings its own problems with it (and additionally in some versions in PHP I've found out the hard way that they only function in the place they were defined and methods called from there, but not in submethods called from within the methods).

Comment: :i try this not showing count value but my query return more than one row

Comment: im missing references, i mean he could add an optional parameter `&$count` which also solves it